# Can't get blob using BlobReferenceProperty

Tags: python, google-app-engine, blobstore

I have an entity which is comprised of a `String` and a `BlobReferenceProperty`:

```
class NameKeyPair(db.Model):
    human_readable_name = db.StringProperty()   
    blobkey = blobstore.BlobReferenceProperty()
```

When I save some text in a blob, I set the blobkey like this:

```
...
#Create the file
file_name = files.blobstore.create(mime_type='text/plain')

#Open the file and write to it
with files.open(file_name, 'a') as f:
    f.write(data.encode('utf8'))

#Finalize the file
files.finalize(file_name)

#Get the file's blob key
blobkey = files.blobstore.get_blob_key(file_name)

#store it in DB
nameKeyPair = NameKeyPair()
nameKeyPair.blobkey = blobkey
nameKeyPair.human_readable_name = human_readable_name
nameKeyPair.put()
...
```

The `human_readable_name` is a string which I send out the user. Now when the user sends me the name back, I want to return the text of the blob:

```
...
human_readable_name = self.request.get('human_readable_name') 
q = NameKeyPair.all()
q.filter("human_readable_name =", human_readable_name)

blobkey = ""
for p in q.run(limit=1):
    blobkey = p.blobkey

blob_info = blobstore.BlobInfo.get(blobkey)
self.send_blob(blob_info)
```

This doesn't work. Appspot just says 'server error.'

If I print out my variable `blobkey` it says `<google.appengine.ext.blobstore.blobstore.BlobInfo object at 0x54dbe8bfa91b53a0>` Shouldn't it be a blobkey?

This page: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/blobstore/blobkeyclass says  "You can fetch the BlobInfo entity with a BlobKey by passing the key to the BlobInfo.get() class method."

That's why I was passing my blobkey to `BlobInfo.get`. But if my "blobkey" is in fact already a `BlobInfo` object, maybe I don't need to do that. I tried passing it directly to `send_blob` instead:

```
self.send_blob(blobkey)
```

But I get the same result.

And based on this page: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/blobstore/ which shows code example: `self.send_blob(blob_info)` it seems like that should be all I need... But it just doesn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: Is there a more detailed error in the log?

Answer (score 0):

I cant comment but try use [object].key() I find it a bit obtuse when is the key an object and when is it a string